# Firebase and Java offline storage

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I know for sure that Firebase can work offline and store locally any changes you made to the database and whenever he get connection again upload the changes, when you're coding on android. This can be used in any Java aplication, or is it only in android? I've searched but find nothing about this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Firebase has a REST API. Anything that can do REST should be able to use Firebase. https://robert-reiz.com/2012/04/22/java-driver-for-firebase/

Comment: this will help a lot, thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*firebaser here*

Disk persistence is only available on iOS and Android. It is not available in the Java Admin SDK.

Comment: thats why i couldn't find nothing about it. Thanks.
By the way do yo know any workaround to acomplish something like that?

Comment: You'd have to build your own wrapper, similar to the JavaScript/polymer version here: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/polymer-firebase-pwa/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#25

Answer (score 0):

`is it only in android?` -- No, as you know Firebase is a technology that permits you to make *mobile and web applications* with no server-side programming so that development turns out to be quicker and easier.

You can use Firebase with-

- Android
- Unity
- IOS
- Web and more

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37905828/how-to-retrieve-firebase-data-in-a-non-android-java-app) SO question.

Also, [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/package-summary) is what I found.