# Use more than one Firebase database in single app - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase database currently connected to my app with the GoogleService-Info.plist, etc. It works great.

I would like to connect my app to a second firebase database as well.

It looks like this problem was solved for Android [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37634767/how-to-connect-to-more-than-one-firebase-database-from-an-android-app).

Any idea how to add a second firebase database with Swift in Xcode?

EDIT: I have tried several approaches, including using FIROptions to set up an instance of a database. I just can't seem to structure the code correctly. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The proper way to initialize another database is to initialize another app, using the `FIROptions` constructor, like so:

```
FIRDatabase().database() // gets you the default database

let options = FIROptions(googleAppID:  bundleID: , GCMSenderID: , APIKey: , clientID: , trackingID: , androidClientID: , databaseURL: "https://othernamespace.firebaseio.com", storageBucket: , deepLinkURLScheme: ) // fill in all the other fields 
FIRApp.configureWithName("anotherClient", options: options)
let app = FIRApp(named: "anotherClient")
FIRDatabase.database(app: app!) // gets you the named other database
```

Or you can initialize from another named plist rather than a huge constructor:

```
let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("MyCool-GoogleService-Info", ofType:"plist")
let options = FIROptions(contentsOfFile:filePath)
```

Comment: Thanks, Mike. I'm glad it's possible.

Comment: Mike, how do we get notified when the release with this feature is released?

Comment: It's all in the release notes: https://firebase.google.com/support/releases. BTW, the method you want is here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseanalytics/interface_f_i_r_options.html#a9a699abf436a6fcf9fd8165a2dfceaf6

Comment: I have Firebase analytics 3.2.0 and Firebase 3.2.1 , initWithContentsOfFile method is not available

Comment: @EhsanR you should update to Firebase 3.6.0, which is the latest and greatest :)

Comment: @MikeMcDonald could you please help me out with an answer to my related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44866220

Answer (score 2):

With the newest version of Firebase you should do:

```
let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "My-GoogleService", ofType: "plist")
guard let fileopts = FirebaseOptions.init(contentsOfFile: filePath!)
      else { assert(false, "Couldn't load config file") }
FirebaseApp.configure(options: fileopts)
```