# How can i store to different storage buckets using Firebase Storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

Is there a way to communicate/store data to another project/application using Firebase Storage? How can I initialize my application to call another Firebase Storage Bucket?

Comment: I don't think its possible

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Referring to this [More than one Firebase Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37634767/how-to-connect-to-more-than-one-firebase-database-from-an-android-app) i just tried to configure the initialization of the Firebase Storage by using

```
   FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setApiKey("AI...j0")
            .setApplicationId("1:5...e0")
            .setDatabaseUrl("https://myapp.firebaseio.com")
            .build();
    FirebaseApp secondApp = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(getApplicationContext(), options, "second app");
    //storage
    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance(secondApp);
    StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://.......");
```

Comment: Good find! Using two projects is indeed a way to write files to two buckets. Within a single project, Firebase Storage will always refer to a single bucket.

Answer (score 2):

While DreamBigAlvin's workaround still works, a simpler way is now [built-in into the Firebase SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/start):

```
StorageReference storageReference = 
    FirebaseStorage.getInstance("gs://my-custom-bucket")
                   .getReference();
```

Comment: Does this still works? It appear that the API changed

Answer (score 1):

#### Update: 2019

According to https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/firebase_storage/latest/firebase_storage/FirebaseStorage-class.html

The method is now:

```dart
StorageReference reference =
      FirebaseStorage(storageBucket: "gs://my-bucket").ref();
```