# Can I initialize Firebase without using google-services.json?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

EDIT: I should emphasize, I have flavors, for which I don't want to use any of these Google services, and attempting to apply the google-services plugin in such a case, without having an applicable google-services.json, would result in a failed build.

I would like to be able to initialize the Firebase SDK, specifically to use the Remote Config, WITHOUT using the google-services.json.

I see that FirebaseApp has an initialize method, which receives a FirebaseOptions object.

I've built the FirebaseOptions with values provided in the google-services.json, and after a call to FirebaseApp.initialize with these options, I always get

```
FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful
```

I know it's the recommended way to use the google-services.json file, but I need to be able to make the app call different Firebase projects, depending on debug/release builds, while keeping the package name the same.

The way I would like to do this is to have a debug/release pairs for all values necessary to initialize Firebase, and then dynamically do the initialization.

```
        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setApplicationId(appId)
                .setApiKey(apiKey)
                .setGcmSenderId(appContext.getString(
                        isDebug ? R.string.firebase_testing_gcm_sender_id :
                                R.string.firebase_production_gcm_sender_id))
                .setDatabaseUrl(appContext.getString(
                        isDebug ? R.string.firebase_testing_database_url :
                                R.string.firebase_production_database_url))
                .setStorageBucket(
                        appContext.getString(
                                isDebug ? R.string.firebase_testing_storage_bucket :
                                        R.string.firebase_production_storage_bucket))
                .build();
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(appContext, options);
```

So far it doesn't seem to work.

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but perhaps helpful:  The documentation for the [Google Services Gradle Plugin](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin#adding_the_json_file) explains that you can have multiple `google-services.json` files for a project to support different build types and flavors.

Comment: @qbix, thanks, I've updated my question. I am aware of this, but the issue is that I have some flavors for which I just don't want to use any of these Google services, since I don't need them. If I don't still provide a google-services.json, the build will fail.

Comment: This worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37634767/how-to-connect-to-more-than-one-firebase-database-from-an-android-app/37643374#37643374. What isn't working for you?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, that's pretty much exactly what I'm doing, and I'm getting the "Initialization unsuccessful" message.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen It could be that, in order to successfully manually initialize the FirebaseApp instance, I have to give it a non-default name, but the problem is that FirebaseRemoteConfig, doesn't have a parametrized getInstance method where I could pass such a non-default FireabaseApp instance, and so when calling FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance, the app crashes.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, nope, tried that, fails to initialize even with a non-default name. Hmmm.

Comment: So i'm trying to do exactly the same thing, but getting an error: Missing google_app_id. Firebase Analytics disabled. - It seems that it requires a resource value. If i provide a invalid value, it crashes, and if I provide a valid one, it uses that no matter what I write in setApplicationId() - any help?

Comment: Sam put together a blog on how to do this: https://medium.com/@samstern_58566/how-to-use-firebase-on-android-without-the-google-services-plugin-93ecc7dc6c4

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here are couple pointers on how to use multiple firebase apps / databases in the same android project [Firebase Blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/12/working-with-multiple-firebase-projects-in-an-android-app.html) and [New Config Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/configure/)

However these talk about using a secondary app in addition to the default app -- which still uses the google-services.json. I did a little bit of research and poking around in their Slack channel. Firebase uses a ContentProvider called FirebaseInitProvider. This uses the google-services.json to initialize the DEFAULT app at start up. It barfs if the json file is not present. I did the following steps:

- Removed the google-services.json
- Removed com.google.gms.google-services plugin. This [plugin](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin) always looks for the json file.
- FirebaseInitProvider is added via manifest merging. However in the top level manifest you can specify a node=remove tag to remove this from being added in the final manifest.

  ```
  <provider android:authorities="${applicationId}.firebaseinitprovider"
      android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" 
      android:exported="false"
      tools:node="remove"/>
  ```

However, even after this, I still see an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process myfirebasedemo.net. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
                                                                 at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                                                                 at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                                                                 at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                 at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService.zzm(Unknown Source)
                                                                 at com.google.firebase.iid.zzb$2.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Looks like FirebaseInstanceIdService still looks for the instance app. If you disable the service, using the same manifest node removal technique then this exception goes away. But I think this Service does important sync-ing / messaging stuff. So not sure if its wise to remove this. Long story short -- I am still looking for the perfect solution for disabling the default app / not using the google-services.json. Any further pointers will be deeply appreciated.

UPDATE:

Looks like this solution works after all -- without disabling the FirebaseInstanceIdService and just removing the FirebaseInitProvider as mentioned above. Just need to make sure that the Firebase.initializeApp called the first thing in Application::onCreate method.

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context, new FirebaseOptions.Builder().setApiKey("<VAL>").
                    setApplicationId("<VAL>").
                    setDatabaseUrl("<VAL>").
                    setGcmSenderId("<VAL>").
                    setStorageBucket("<VAL>").build());
```

Comment: I've tried this and it's not working for me.  What version of Firebase is this?

Comment: @user1743524 i have tried this with version 10.0.1 and seems to work for me.

Comment: @exifguy I'm getting the `Default FirebaseApp is not initialized` error when the app is killed and I receive a push notification (using the same method as mentioned above). Does this scenario work for you?

Answer (score 5):

The `google-services.json` is totally optional and meant to be convenient.  So if you find it *inconvenient* then definitely don't use it.

As you may have noticed, the `json` file is only used at build time.  The `google-services` plugin turns the JSON file into a resources `xml` file containing some specific strings.  It looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <! -- Present in all applications -->
    <string name="google_app_id" translatable="false">1:1035469437089:android:73a4fb8297b2cd4f</string>

    <! -- Present in applications with the appropriate services configured -->
    <string name="gcm_defaultSenderId" translatable="false">1035469437089</string>
    <string name="default_web_client_id" translatable="false">337894902146-e4uksm38sne0bqrj6uvkbo4oiu4hvigl.apps.googleusercontent.com</string>
    <string name="ga_trackingId" translatable="false">UA-65557217-3</string>
    <string name="firebase_database_url" translatable="false">https://example-url.firebaseio.com</string>
    <string name="google_api_key" translatable="false">AIzbSyCILMsOuUKwN3qhtxrPq7FFemDJUAXTyZ8</string>
    <string name="google_crash_reporting_api_key" translatable="false">AIzbSyCILMsOuUKwN3qhtxrPq7FFemDJUAXTyZ8</string>
    <string name="project_id" translatable="false">mydemoapp</string>

</resources>
```

You can just create these entries in your own `strings.xml` file and then `FirebaseApp.initializeApp()` will find them at runtime.  Not all of the keys are required, it depends what service you're using.  For example almost all services require the `google_app_id` key.  Firestore only needs that and the `project_id`, while Firebase Auth needs the `google_api_key` as well.  It shouldn't be too hard to experiment and figure out which ones you need.

Some links:

- [How to use Firebase on Android without the google-services plugin](https://medium.com/@samstern_58566/how-to-use-firebase-on-android-without-the-google-services-plugin-93ecc7dc6c4)
- [The Google Services Gradle Plugin](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin)

Comment: Can I initialize Firebase programatically without using strings.xml or google-services.json at all?

Answer (score 2):

I've found interesting workaround. Try the following:
put your `google-services.json` to any sample app google [provides](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android) for Firebase integration. Compile it.

Take a look on path `app/build/generated/res/google-services/debug/values/`  there should be generated `values.xml` file with bunch of strings mentioned in errors you described. Copy these strings to value.xml file of your project. That's it.

Comment: Worked for me, too. You must not forget to remove `FirebaseInitProvider` from the manifest.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also using build variants for applying different configurations for different environments.
I had the same issue, as some of the variants didn't have an appropriate entry on the `google-services.json` file. that caused some of my builds to fail when generating an app package that was not configured in firebase.

My workaround for this was to add dummy applications entries for the missing packages on the relevant firebase projects, on the firebase dashboard - then getting the updated `google-services.json` file from it.

Might not be the best practice, but did the job in my case.