# Is it possible to configure Firebase analytics without google-services.json configuration file?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I would like to use Firebase analytics for one of my library modules. I would like to program in such a way that configuration file (`google-services.json`) should be accessible from either client app folder or configure the same from the client side.

Is there a way I could implement the above mentioned scenario?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38962025/can-i-initialize-firebase-without-using-google-services-json/44396850#44396850

Answer (score 3):

You can initialize your library project configurations manually as below,

For more info, kindly refer [working-with-multiple-firebase-projects-in-an-android-app](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/12/working-with-multiple-firebase-projects-in-an-android-app.html)

Also go-through [how-does-firebase-initialize-on-android](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/12/how-does-firebase-initialize-on-android.html) to understand; how the Firebase module is getting initialized by itself.

> For Android apps using Firebase, there is a central FirebaseApp object
>   that manages the configuration for all the Firebase APIs. This is
>   initialized automatically by a content provider when your app is
>   launched, and you typically never need to interact with it. However,
>   when you want to access multiple projects from a single app, you'll
>   need a distinct FirebaseApp to reference each one individually. It's
>   up to you to initialize the instances other than the default that
>   Firebase creates for you.

```
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
       .setApplicationId("1:530266078999:android:481c4ecf3253701e") // Required for Analytics.
       .setApiKey("AIzaSyBRxOyIj5dJkKgAVPXRLYFkdZwh2Xxq51k") // Required for Auth.
       .setDatabaseUrl("https://project-1765055333176374514.firebaseio.com/") // Required for RTDB.
       .build();
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this /* Context */, options, "secondary");
```

Hope I've answered your question.

Comment: Missing *google_app_id*. Firebase Analytics disabled. This error is getting now

Comment: @ArunChand Did you initialized with valid app_id, in setApplicationId("mobilesdk_app_id") ?

Comment: You need to get your app_id from "google-services.json". under "client": [ {"client_info" { "mobilesdk_app_id" = "xxxxxx" }} ]

Answer (score 2):

I've found interesting workaround. Try the following:
put your `google-services.json` to any sample app google [provides](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android) for Firebase integration. Compile it.

Take a look on path `app/build/generated/res/google-services/debug/values/`  there should be generated `values.xml` file with bunch of strings mentioned in errors you described. Copy these strings to value.xml file of your project. That's it.

Comment: Please confirm that google-services.json does nothing other than this. Why they have invented the bicycle, but do not recommend just copy paste several strings to your resources?