# Is possible to use two firebase project in a single android application? if it is possible. how?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

i have an android application that has 2 user. if the first user register in the app then it's information will save in firebase auth of the first project and if the second user register in the same app, its information will save in firebase auth of second project. the two project is in one firebase acccount. is possible to use two firebase project in a single android application? if it is possible. how?

Comment: Why do you want to store same info in separate database?

Comment: the two users in the my application are student and teacher. i created a login page with a spinner that has two value and it is student and teacher. everytime that i register. all information are stored in firebase project which has one firebase auth. i want if student login their account,they will redirect to requested page and if teacher login their account they will also redirect to requested page but different from the requested page of student. i can do this thing but my problem is if i login as a student and i enter teacher information to login page.it still redirect me to requested page

Comment: You can access two Firebase projects within a single Android app. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37634767/how-to-connect-to-more-than-one-firebase-database-from-an-android-app/37643374#37643374. If you're having problems implementing something, share the [**minimal** code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link, it is quite useful) to get help