# read firebase realtime data from other firebase project

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

We have 2 Firebase projects, the first one used for management different applications and projects and the other holds users of one of applications.

We need to allow the management project to modify the users project's details.

Is there anyway we can do it without defining the read and write rules of the users project as true, meaning everyone have access to its data.

Comment: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/12/working-with-multiple-firebase-projects-in-an-android-app.html

Comment: If you're using Android, also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37634767/how-to-connect-to-more-than-one-firebase-database-from-an-android-app