# Select Firebase database in runtime

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

I would like to give the user the option to select which Firebase Real-time database to use.
Essentially I am using multiple Firebase databases in a single apk.
As this happens in runtime I won’t be able to use the google-services.json file to connect to Firebase.
I used this blog as reference but still couldn’t connect to the database .

---

[Blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/take-control-of-your-firebase-init-on.html?m=1)

Blog post - https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/take-control-of-your-firebase-init-on.html?m=1

---

Is there a solution where I could connect to Firebase database in runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't rely on the google services plugin to read the data from `google-services.json`, you can also specify the relevant data in your code when you initialize the `FirebaseApp` instance:

```
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
        .setApiKey("AI...j0")
        .setApplicationId("1:5...e0")
        .setDatabaseUrl("https://myapp.firebaseio.com")
        .build();
FirebaseApp firebaseApp = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(getApplicationContext(), options, "second app");
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(firebaseApp);
database.getReference().setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
```

You will have to get the relevant values from the `google-services.json` or the Firebase console.

Also see my answer here: [How to connect to more than one firebase database from an android App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37634767/how-to-connect-to-more-than-one-firebase-database-from-an-android-app)