# Firebase Apple Auth not working with .aab file

Tags: kotlin, firebase-authentication, apk, android-app-bundle, apple-authentication

So I have enabled apple auth within my Firebase console and have already done all the steps needed to activate it within my apple console. Everything works just fine with a signed .apk file but when I push my package in.aab format to the Playstore I get the error **"There was an error while trying to get your package certificate hash"** when I try to use the apple sign-in method.

Has anyone faced this issue before?

Comment: Seems like same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56979378/firebase-auth-on-a-project-other-than-the-one-the-android-application-is-added-t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who might have the same issue, this problem stems from Playstore, having the policy to sign the AAB file again when converting it to the APK file, hence the actual signing SHA that needs to be added to the Firebase Console is the Playstore key SHA rather than your own key(meaning the key that turns the AAB file to an APK package)