# Login with different console Firebase (different users)?

Tags: android, firebase

it's possible to create an android application(related to Firebase) which provides to every user the ability 
to connect to his own firebase , without sharing his information with other users( not the collaboration method ,generally, the app is 
about to track object : the user connect to app , get the object information and store it in his account and  than track it) .. so any solution for the login process ?

Comment: Do you mean to say having a custom object inside firebase user Object?

Comment: @erluxman  no not that the problem , all i need is to find a way that the application could connect to different users console( for example mine,  yours ,and other users  )  independently ( the issue is that the app is related to a project which is under a console one person (the owner) ) , okay ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which backend resources your Android code connects to is determined by the `FirebaseApp` instance. The default app is usually initialized from the `google-services.json` that you add to your project, so can't be dynamically changed from within the code.

But you can also initialize a `FirebaseApp` instance from within your Android code. All you need is the pertinent information from the Firebase project of the user, which would otherwise be read from their `google-services.json`. You'll want to [build](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/FirebaseOptions.Builder.html) a [`FirebaseOptions` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/FirebaseOptions.html) in that case, which contains things like the Application ID, Project ID, Database URL and a few more values.

Once you have a `FirebaseApp`, you can then get the other Firebase services from that. It's quite similar to my answer on [accessing multiple databases in a single app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37634767/how-to-connect-to-more-than-one-firebase-database-from-an-android-app) from a few years ago. From there:

> ```
> FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
>         .setApiKey("AI...j0")
>         .setApplicationId("1:5...e0")
>         .setDatabaseUrl("https://myapp.firebaseio.com")
>         .build();
> FirebaseApp secondApp = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(getApplicationContext(), options, "second app");
> FirebaseDatabase secondDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(secondApp);
> secondDatabase.getReference().setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
> ```