# is there any alternative for APP_ID and API_KEY?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

We are developing an SDK for developers which in core depends on Firebase to get tokens, therefore we are using `FirebaseOptions` to initialize our `firebaseInstance`

In the new [firebase updates](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#messaging_v20-1-1) they said: we should provide *APP_ID* and *API_KEY*.

Is there any alternative for that as SDK developers?

If not, is there a way to get *API_KEY* from dashboard instead of download the **googel-service.json** and extract from it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both API key and App ID can be found in the Firebase console too.

The API key you need is called <kbd>Web API Key</kbd> and can be found in the [general gettings](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/settings/general) screen in the Firebase console.

The App ID can be found when you select a specific app from that general setting screen, and is under the label <kbd>App ID</kbd>

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is the correct key though. Also see the example in the docs here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects#use_multiple_projects_in_your_application and my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37634767/how-to-connect-to-more-than-one-firebase-database-from-an-android-app. It may help if you say what specifically doesn't work after you enter this key. Is there an error message?

Comment: Sorry Frank, I Just missed with another key (APP_ID), A lot of keys now ^^

Comment: Yeah, as you add more apps, it becomes a bit of a key soup. In that sense I'm always impressed that the apps can find their keys in that jungle, even when I know exactly how they do that. :)

Comment: OMG, Did `20.1.6` ask for project-id too? LOL, Our client must provide 4 keys from firebase side only... I hope there is another alternative.