# Switch google-services.json in run-time

Tags: firebase, flutter

Is there a way to switch google-services.json file on run-time?

If yes, a code sample is highly appreciated

Thank you

Comment: You are free to write code to initialize the Firebase SDK with whatever values you like, whenever you like, without a json file.

Comment: Adding to what @DougStevenson said, you can use [this](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_core/latest/firebase_core/FirebaseApp/configure.html) method.

Comment: It might also help if you look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37634767/how-to-connect-to-more-than-one-firebase-database-from-an-android-app/37643374#37643374

Comment: different approach might be to use [link](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_core) , but I can not get the FirebaseAuth from FirebaseApp object

Comment: @DougStevenson : so if i have the following code `final FirebaseOptions SecondayDB_options = const FirebaseOptions(
    googleAppID: '1:7931046381656:android:2fb28f95a41bde78da062d',

    gcmSenderID: '7931046381656',
    apiKey: 'AIzaSyAvG7mVHoX0C_zim1D3UhUITF4ml7Be4fsI',
  );`  and  ` final FirebaseApp app = await FirebaseApp.configure(
      name: 'FB-1',
      options: SecondayDB_options,
    );`  what is the next step ? how do I get  the FirebaseAuth object related?

Comment: If you have another question, please post it separately.