# single android project with multiple firebase projects

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

We have an android app for which we have separate firebase projects for each country. Earlier, we had a separate apk for each country and the firebase projects were pre-configured for each project.

The main projects were the same but only the backend and firebase projects were different for the sake of some data compliance issues.

Now, we are working on merging all those projects into a single apk so that the backend and firebase projects will be selected based on the user's login country code.

On playstore, there is a single application that users install. When the user logs in using his phone number, Based on his country dial code, the android app will select the firebase project related to the user's country code.

Currently, the android app is using a single firebase project which is preconfigured in the configuration of the apk. My question is whether it is possible to change the android project on run time or do we always have to preconfigure the firebase project in the android project?

Comment: Yes, selecting a project at runtime is possible and supported. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37634767/how-to-connect-to-more-than-one-firebase-database-from-an-android-app/37643374#37643374

Answer (score 2):

Good question.

We can't create more than one firebase project with same application id.

From my guess you are used different application id for each project before.

And you can manage projects as single project with build variant (many application id's and firebase config using flavors).

Firebase configuration always preconfigured.